# MyBattis mapper for a table with compound primary key

Tags: java, mysql, database, mybatis, ibatis

We have a mysql table with compound primary key. The table is holding items. 
Then we have itemId, itemName, itemType,  lang, shortDescription, LongDescription and some other fields.The keys are itemId and lang. It means that item with ID one can be repeated for English and spanish and based on this we have different short and long descriptions. The database is not normalized and it will not be normalized either.  I have written a Java bean for Item which looks like this:

```
public class Item {
    private String itemId;
    private String itemName;
    private String itemType;
    List<LangDescription> langdescriptions;

    public String getItemId() {
        return itemId;
    }

    public void setItemId(String itemId) {
        this.itemId = itemId;
    }

    public String getItemName() {
        return itemName;
    }

    public void setItemName(String itemName) {
        this.itemName = itemName;
    }

    public String getItemType() {
        return itemType;
    }

    public void setItemType(String itemType) {
        this.itemType = itemType;
    }

    public List<LangDescription> getLangdescriptions() {
        return langdescriptions;
    }

    public void setLangdescriptions(List<LangDescription> langdescriptions) {
        this.langdescriptions = langdescriptions;
    }
}
```

where The lang description is another Java bean containing lang, shortDescription and LongDescription.

Now I want to write a mapper using MyBatis to select all rows from the table Item with same column names as field names (itemId, itemType, lang, shortDescription, longDescription) and create a list of Items.

```
    public interface CRMTermsAndConditionsMapper {
    static final String SELECT_ITEMS = "SELECT * FROM items;";

    @Select(SELECT_ITEMS)
    List<Item> selectItems();

}
```

Any suggestion how this can be done? Shall I use a TypeHandler or is it better to use Collectons and @Result annotations?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using mapper interfaces, you should use the [`@Many`](http://www.mybatis.org/mybatis-3/java-api.html) select annotation,

```
public interface CRMTermsAndConditionsMapper {
    static final String SELECT_ITEMS = "SELECT * FROM items;";
    static final String SELECT_LANG_DESC = "SELECT * FROM lang_description;";

    @Select(SELECT_ITEMS)
    @Results({
        @Result(property="langdescriptions",column="langdescriptions",
                javaType=List.class,many=@Many(select="getLangDescriptions"))
    })
    List<Item> selectItems();

    @Select(SELECT_LANG_DESC)
    public List<LangDescription> getLangDescriptions();

}
```

Change the `SELECT_LANG_DESC` query accordingly to select the lang descriptions.